# Is there a way to ignore a non-matching case?

Tags: scala

If I have a `match` expression, how can I make it automatically ignore a non-match **without** explicitly doing `case _ =>`? Is there a way to create a function that does something like this maybe?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need a generic way to handle "ignoring".  Options, among other classes, provide this (among other things).  So you can:

```
val i = 7
Some(i) collect {
  case 3 => "Yay!"
  case 5 => "Boo!"
}
```

to get `None` (typed as an `Option[String]`).  So basically, if you change `x match` to `Some(x) collect` you get the functionality you want.  It is better to do this when one is comfortable with handling options.

Comment: Scala3 it seems, is tighter hence complains on collect similarly as with match.

Answer (score 11):

Write a generic matcher:

```
object Match {
    def default: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = { case _ => }
    def apply[T](x: T)(body: PartialFunction[T, Unit]) = (body orElse default)(x)
}
```

Example:

```
scala> 1 to 5 foreach (Match(_) {
     |   case 2 => println("two")
     |   case 3 => println("three")
     | }
     | )
two
three
```

You might be interested too in `PartialFunction`'s companion object's methods `cond` and `condOpt`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is there not any equivalent builtin of a 'collect' type function for 'foreach'?

Comment: @MatthewSaltz There isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Any match block that can't handle all possible input values forms a Partial Function, which is absolutely possible to define and use in Scala.

`PartialFunction` is a subclass of `Function`, and adds the `isDefinedAt` method, which returns true if it has a defined match for the supplied value.  Partial Functions are best used in places that test for definition, such as catch blocks or the `collect` method in the 2.8 collections API.  Otherwise, you'll get an exception if you try to call it with a value that isn't defined as an input.

Comment: Beyond the exception, I believe you would also get a warning at the definition site, wouldn't you?